# Transposing to get single row for each ID's in R

Tags: r, transpose

```
EID   Year Performance_rating
E100  2013                  4
E100  2014                  1
E200  2012                  4
E200  2013                  5
E200  2014                  2
E200  2015                  4
```

The way i need the data for the modeling purpose is non duplicated EID with there performance rating for each year in separate columns (Note some have 2 years of data and some 3 and some 4 based on there joining date)

```
EID Performance_rating_2012 Performance_rating_2013 Performance_rating_2014 Performance_rating_2015
E100                     NA                       4                       1                      NA
E200                      4                       5                       2                       4
```

I tried multiple methods solving this but failed so posting here ,any answers would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df1, EID~ paste0("Performance_rating_", Year), value.var="Performance_rating")
#  EID Performance_rating_2012 Performance_rating_2013 Performance_rating_2014 Performance_rating_2015
#1 E100                      NA                       4                       1                      NA
#2 E200                       4                       5                       2                       4
```

Comment: Can we perform multiple columns on value.var ,i tried c("Performance_rating,"BGU") but getting error "Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Comment: @Sandeep You can use data.table, as explained in Arun's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30517531

Answer (score 3):

The package `tidyr` has the exact solution needed for this situation and others:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% spread(Year, Performance_rating)
```

Resulting output is the wide data frame:

```
   EID 2012 2013 2014 2015
1 E100   NA    4    1   NA
2 E200    4    5    2    4
```