# cast column entries horizontally in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks similarly to this one

```
  ID  Members  Gender    Age

  1     2       1        35
  1     2       2        33
  2     3       1        54
  2     3       2        50
  2     3       1        15
  3     1       1        65
```

I want to transform it in this way

```
  ID  Members  Gender_1 Gender_2 Gender_3    Age_1 Age_2 Age_3

  1    2         1        2       NA          35    33    NA
  2    3         1        2       1           54    50    15
  3    1         1        NA      NA          65    NA    NA
```

I tried using

```
answer2<-data.table::dcast(df, ID ~ Members, value.var=c("Gender","Age"))
```

following this thread [Reshape multiple value columns to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608167/reshape-multiple-value-columns-to-wide-format), but I still get the same error

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) :    recursive indexing failed
>   at level 2 In addition: Warning message: In if (!(value.var %in%
>   names(data))) { :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first
>   element will be used

Could please anyone help me?
Many thanks

Comment: you need to convert your data to data.table first. Try `library(data.table) ; setDT(df) ; dcast(df, ID ~ Members, value.var=c("Gender","Age"))`

Comment: Broadly speaking, I'm not sure this is a good idea, as it will be easier to work with this data in long form. If there's some significance to the row order, add it as a variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! It works.