# Construct a column getting elements from another table in R

Tags: r

Given a big table, in which there are two important columns:

1. nation code
2. time

```
Name     Nation code     Time       Other
a        IT              2010       x
b        DE              2011       y
c        ES              2009       z
```

I want to construct another column using those two indicators to take the data from another table, which is built like the following

```
Nation code     Y2009     Y2010      Y2011
DE              200       100        300
ES              100       150        350
GB              200       250        50
IT              50        150        100
```

The final result should be the following

```
Name     Nation code     Time       Other       NewColumn
a        IT              2010       x           150
b        DE              2011       y           300
c        ES              2009       z           100
```

Comment: The stack tag-recommendation system is imperfect. Your [tag:datatable] tag is not relevant here, as (if you mouse over it) it is too ambiguous and should really not be used in R. If you mean the `data.table` package then use the [tag:data.table] tag. If you mean generally a `data.frame`, then there's the `[data.frame]` tag (though admittedly that doesn't really add much context here on SO, most [r]-users who answer here are well-versed in frames.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you want, you'll need to perform two steps: First you'll want `df2` in a long format (e.g. using `pivot_longer`), and then you'd do a left join with `df1` (e.g. using `left_join`).

I.e.:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2_long <-
  df2 |> 
  pivot_longer(-Nation_code, names_prefix = "Y", names_to = "Time", values_to = "new_col") |>
  mutate(Time = as.numeric(Time))

# # A tibble: 12 × 3
# Nation_code  Time new_col
# <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>
#   1 DE           2009     200
# 2 DE           2010     100
# 3 DE           2011     300
# 4 ES           2009     100
# 5 ES           2010     150
# 6 ES           2011     350
# 7 GB           2009     200
# 8 GB           2010     250
# 9 GB           2011      50
# 10 IT           2009      50
# 11 IT           2010     150
# 12 IT           2011     100

df1 |>
  left_join(df2_long, by = c("Nation_code", "Time"))
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  Name  Nation_code  Time Other new_col
  <chr> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1 a     IT           2010 x         150
2 b     DE           2011 y         300
3 c     ES           2009 z         100
```

Data:

```r
library(readr)

df1 <- read_table("Name     Nation_code     Time       Other
a        IT              2010       x
b        DE              2011       y
c        ES              2009       z")

df2 <- read_table("Nation_code     Y2009     Y2010      Y2011
DE              200       100        300
ES              100       150        350
GB              200       250        50
IT              50        150        100")
```

Answer (score 1):

### base R (and `reshape2`)

```r
reshape2::melt(df2, "Nation_code", variable.name = "Time", value.name = "NewColumn") |>
  transform(Time = as.integer(sub("\\D", "", Time))) |>
  merge(df1, by = c("Nation_code", "Time"), all.y = TRUE)
#   Nation_code Time NewColumn Name Other
# 1          DE 2011       300    b     y
# 2          ES 2009       100    c     z
# 3          IT 2010       150    a     x
```

### data.table

```r
# library(data.table)
DT1 <- as.data.table(df1)
DT2 <- as.data.table(df2)
DT1[
  melt(DT2, "Nation_code", variable.name = "Time", value.name = "NewColumn"
    )[, Time := as.integer(sub("\\D", "", Time))],
  NewColumn := i.NewColumn, on = .(Nation_code, Time)][]
#      Name Nation_code  Time  Other NewColumn
#    <char>      <char> <int> <char>     <int>
# 1:      a          IT  2010      x       150
# 2:      b          DE  2011      y       300
# 3:      c          ES  2009      z       100
```

This is a combination of two frequent questions on SO:

- Pivoting wide-to-long, [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272;) for reference, there's also long-to-wide, [Reshape multiple value columns to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11608167/3358272)
- Merge/join, see [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272) and [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table("Name     Nation_code     Time       Other
a        IT              2010       x
b        DE              2011       y
c        ES              2009       z")

df1 <- read_table("Nation_code     Y2009     Y2010      Y2011
DE              200       100        300
ES              100       150        350
GB              200       250        50
IT              50        150        100")

df1 <- df1 %>%  
  pivot_longer(-Nation_code, 
               names_to = "Time", 
               values_to = "NewColumn") %>%  
  mutate(Time = Time %>% str_remove_all("Y") %>%  
           as.numeric)

df %>%  
  left_join(df1, by = c("Nation_code", "Time"))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Name  Nation_code  Time Other NewColumn
  <chr> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1 a     IT           2010 x           150
2 b     DE           2011 y           300
3 c     ES           2009 z           100
```

Answer (score 0):

Preparing the input tables:

```
a <- data.frame(
  "Name" = c("a","b","c"),
  "Nation_Code" = c("IT", "DE", "ES"),
  "Time" = c(2010, 2011, 2009),
  "Other" = c("x", "y", "z")
)

b <- data.frame(
  "Nation_Code" = c("DE", "ES", "GB", "IT"),
  "Y2009" = c(200,100,200,50),
  "Y2010" = c(100,150,250,150),
  "Y2011" = c(300,350,50,100)
)
```

This is how I would go about it: First, you need to convert the second table from the so-called "wide format" to the "long format". You can do this with `gather()`. This means, that instead of having multiple columns with values, you will have one column containing the former column names and one column containing the values. Next, you have to change the strings "Y20xx" into numerics. This can be done with `mutate()` which creates a new column or overwrites an old column. I took the last 4 letters of each string and converted them to numerics. Then, you can join the tables using one of the `join()` functions (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html). The `inner_join()` only keeps entries which are present in both data frames.

```
# loading the necessary package    
library (tidyverse)

combined <- b %>%
  gather(key = "Time", value = "NewColumn", -("Nation_Code")) %>% # wide format to long format
  mutate(Time = as.numeric(substr(Time, 2, 5))) %>% # change year format to numeric
  inner_join(a, by= c("Time" = "Time", "Nation_Code" = "Nation_Code")) # join the tables

>   Nation_Code Time NewColumn Name Other
> 1          ES 2009       100    c     z
> 2          IT 2010       150    a     x
> 3          DE 2011       300    b     y
```