# I have three datasets of libraries for the past 3 years. I want to take those datasets to make a new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I have three datasets of ontario libraries for the past 3 years. The data sets have various information about the libraries, their address, city, card holders,etc. I created a dataset to combine all of the data sets into one new data set called data combined.

```
like so
data_2017<- read.csv("Downloads/2017.csv")
data_2016<- read.csv("Downloads/2016.csv")
data_2015<- read.csv("Downloads/2015.csv")

common_columns <- Reduce(intersect, list(colnames(data_2017), colnames(data_2016),colnames(data_2015)))
data_combined <- rbind(
  subset(data_2017, select = common_columns),
  subset(data_2016, select = common_columns),
  subset(data_2015, select = common_columns)
)

write.csv(data_combined, "Downloads.csv")
```

What I need help with is that I need write a sequence of code which will create a single data set that can be used to output a table that lists the number of libraries in each city for the last 3 years. In excel I would use the count function to see the amount of libraries each cities has... to create a new table. I need help with the equivalent in R. I want to make a new table that will have the cities names on the row header and the columns will be the sum of the libraries for each year 2015, 2016 and 2017.
I want to make a new dataframe like this:
[INSTEAD OF 1999, 2000 and 2001.. I want it to say 2015, 2016 and 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm3ss.png)

Here is where you can find the data set for 2015, 2016 and 2017 [here is where you can find the datasets.. only use 2015, 2016 and 2017](https://data.ontario.ca/dataset/ontario-public-library-statistics)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like [Calculate the mean by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272) for summarizing by group, then [Reshape multiple value columns to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11608167/3358272) for pivoting from long to wide. However, this is complicated by the fact that some data have commas, rendering them as `character` instead of `numeric`, so rbinding them will be problematic. Here's a pipe that should take care of all of that.

I've downloaded those three files to my `~/Downloads/` directory, then

```r
library(dplyr)

alldat <- lapply(grep("ontario", list.files("~/Downloads/", full.names=TRUE), value = TRUE), read.csv)
common_columns <- Reduce(intersect, sapply(alldat, names))

data_combined <- alldat %>%
  lapply(function(dat) as.data.frame(
    lapply(dat, function(z) if (all(grepl("^[0-9.,]*$", z))) type.convert(gsub(",", "", z), as.is = TRUE) else z)
    )) %>%
  lapply(subset, select = common_columns) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  tibble() %>%
  count(City = A1.10.City.Town, Year = Survey.Year.From) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(City, names_from = Year, values_from = n)

data_combined
# # A tibble: 336 x 4
#    City         `2015` `2016` `2017`
#    <chr>         <int>  <int>  <int>
#  1 Addison           1      1      1
#  2 Ajax              1      1      1
#  3 Alderville        1      1      1
#  4 Algoma Mills      1      1      1
#  5 Alliston          2      2      2
#  6 Almonte           1      1      1
#  7 Amaranth          1      1      1
#  8 Angus             1      1      1
#  9 Apsley            1      1      1
# 10 Arnprior          2      2      2
# # ... with 326 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you!! I love your approach. It makes a lot of sense. For some reason when I run it this error occurs:    Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  embedded nul(s) found in input  Error in `group_by()`:
! Problem adding computed columns.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `City = A1.10.City.Town`.
Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_mutate()`:
! object 'A1.10.City.Town' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: I don't know, you see my code, it doesn't have that error. Then again, I don't call `group_by`.

Comment: ya your code works, I'll try to play around with it so I don't get that error

Comment: I know you don't call by group by I'm just confused as to how I get that error when I copy your code from the backtrace here are my results: Backtrace:
  1. ... %>% ...
  4. dplyr:::count.data.frame(., City = A1.10.City.Town, Year = Survey.Year.From)
  6. dplyr:::group_by.data.frame(x, ..., .add = TRUE, .drop = .drop)
  7. dplyr::group_by_prepare(.data, ..., .add = .add, caller_env = caller_env())
  8. dplyr:::add_computed_columns(...)
 10. dplyr:::mutate_cols(...)
 12. mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)