# How do I change row data into a column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I currently have a data frame that looks as follows:

| Week | Publisher | Perc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | De Telegraaf | 0.597 |
| 1 | De Volkskrant | 0.874 |
| 2 | De Telegraaf | 3.761 |
| 2 | De Volkskrant | 4.123 |

However, I want to have it like this:

| Week | TelegraafPerc | VolkskrantPerc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.597 | 0.874 |
| 2 | 3.761 | 4.123 |

I honestly have no clue in how to make

```
Publisher
```

into a Column and link it to the relevant

```
Perc
```

in order to sort it by

```
Week
```

```
data:

structure(list(Week = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Publisher = c("De Telegraaf", 
"De Volkskrant", "De Telegraaf", "De Volkskrant"), Perc = c(0.597, 
0.874, 3.761, 4.123)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: We could use `pivot_wider`: `library(tidyr) library(dplyr) df %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Publisher,
    values_from =Perc
  )`

Comment: These two analogous datasets are generally referred to as “long” and “wide” - as you continue to learn this terminology will be useful as you search for solutions. Good luck!

Comment: This is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/11608167/3358272. Two methods include: `tidyr::pivot_wider(dat, "Week", names_from = "Publisher", values_from = "Perc")` and `reshape2::dcast(Week ~ Publisher, data = dat, value.var = "Perc")`.

Comment: Or you can use akrun's since-deleted `data.table` code: `dcast(setDT(df1), Week ~ Publisher, value.var = 'Perc')` (truncated for terseness, recognizing that this generates column names with spaces, just a _little_ more work to use them in R).