# How to append duplicated rows as additional columns of the same key value in R?

Tags: r, duplicates, transformation

I want to spread the duplicated rows based on the key value (which is name of the car in this case).
I've tried different ways to get the result I wanted. But I'm kinda stuck.

Say, this is the dataframe that I have.

[image]

I want the result to be something like this. (used bind_cols() just to show my desired output)

[image]

So basically, I want to spread the duplicated rows based on the key value (which is name of the car in this case).

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variant of [Reshape multiple value columns to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11608167/3358272):

Hasty data:

```r
quux <- rbind(tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars[1:3,], "key"), tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars[1:3,], "key"))
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_wider
quux %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(key, names_from=rn, values_from=-c(key, rn), names_vary = "slowest")
# # A tibble: 3 × 23
#   key           mpg_1 cyl_1 disp_1  hp_1 drat_1  wt_1 qsec_1  vs_1  am_1 gear_1 carb_1 mpg_2 cyl_2 disp_2  hp_2 drat_2  wt_2 qsec_2  vs_2  am_2 gear_2 carb_2
#   <chr>         <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 Mazda RX4      21       6    160   110   3.9   2.62   16.5     0     1      4      4  21       6    160   110   3.9   2.62   16.5     0     1      4      4
# 2 Mazda RX4 Wag  21       6    160   110   3.9   2.88   17.0     0     1      4      4  21       6    160   110   3.9   2.88   17.0     0     1      4      4
# 3 Datsun 710     22.8     4    108    93   3.85  2.32   18.6     1     1      4      1  22.8     4    108    93   3.85  2.32   18.6     1     1      4      1
```

Comment: This is just what I wanted. I see pivot function can be used quite usefully in this case. Thanks for the help!