# Converting rows to columns with meaningful duplicate rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to convert rows to columns using the tidyverse package, but I am getting an error message about duplicate data. However, I need to keep this data.

My data frame looks like this :

| Agent | Job |
| --- | --- |
| Agent A | Job 1 |
| Agent B | Job 1 |
| Agent A | Job 2 |
| Agent C | Job 2 |
| Agent B | Job 3 |

I would like to put the agents as rows, so it would have a single row per agent. However, it is important that I see that both job 1 and job 2 have the agent A.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is a sample data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
sample.df <- data.frame(Agent = c("Agent A", "Agent B", "Agent A", "Agent C ", "Agent B"),
           Job = c(1,1,2,2,3))

sample.df %>%
  rownames_to_column(sample.df$Agent)
```

Comment: Your frame does not have row names. See `rownames(sample.df)` to confirm that they are just R's default of numbering them. (`rownames_to_columns` does not reshape a frame, it merely adds _one_ column alongside existing columns.) I think you need `tidyr::pivot_wider(sample.df, id_cols = Agent, names_from = Job, values_from = ...)`, though I don't know what you would need as the `...` since there is no "value" column in your sample data.

Comment: I think you need "reshaping", aka pivot/dcast. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11608167/3358272.

Comment: Try `sample.df %>% mutate(hasjob = TRUE) %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = Agent, names_from = Job, values_from = hasjob)` for an option.

Comment: I probably should've put it in my original question @r2evans, but each job has a probability of exposure to any given agent. Therefore, in my final dataframe I would have each agent as a column and the jobs as rows with probabilities under the agents

Comment: Then remove my `mutate` and change `values_from=hasjob` to `values_from=exposure` or whatever. More-representative data will be justified if all of the current answers don't work for you.

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to pivot wide. You would see each column that the agent has.

```
library(tidyverse)
sample.df %>%
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = Job,
        values_from = c(Job)
    )
```