# How to merge rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm new to coding with R, and need to find a way to edit my data frame for a stacked bar plot using R. I need one column with character values, followed by two columns with numeric values. This is the code that produced this table:

[image: dataframe]

```r
prize_type_per_gender <- literary_cleaned %>%
  group_by(gender, prize_type) %>%
  summarize (n())
```

I need to write it so that each gender is combined, with one column for each prize type as a number. So it would be gender, book, career as the headings. Any help is appreciated!

I tried to filter it but I'm sure I'm not doing it correctly: filter (prize_type, "book" = TRUE)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, @JMII! Lots of people here will be willing to help, but you're *far* more likely to receive that help if you follow SO customs: provide your data (i.e., a `dput()` of your data) so a reproducible example is possible. Thanks!

Comment: This is almost certainly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11608167/3358272. Try tidyr::`pivot_wider(prize_type_per_gender, id_cols=gender, names_from=prize_type, values_from=\`n()\`)`. If that doesn't work, either [edit] your question to add sample data as requested, or recognize that your question will likely be closed as "not reproducible" or "needs details". (Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for ways to ask a question in a way that is _reproducible_. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Remove the pronoun information after the slash in the gender category ('nonbinary/he' and 'nonbinary/they' could be different columns, but I'm guessing because one has book, and the other has career, they are meant to be in the same column. You could potentially include preferred pronoun as a column if you like! Though in that case, I would keep the data long, and not make it wide)
2. Pivot the data wider, in the standard way (I would explain this, but this has explained in many ways, many times, including the documentation, and the questions r2evans linked)

```
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  mutate(gender = str_remove(gender, "/.*")) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = prize_type, values_from = n)
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text="
gender prize_type n
female book 1007  
female career 1476 
male book 1766 
male career 2788 
nonbinary/he book 1 
nonbinary/they career 2
unknown book 3
unknown career 1", h=T)
```

Note: Instead of using `summarise(n())`, you can just use `count()`, which does the same thing (and also saves the column being called `n()`, which you have to surround with `s to select (which is kinda annoying!). If you do want to use summarise(), I recommend giving the column a name, e.g. `summarise(n = n())`. I assume the column is called `n` for the purposes of this question.